# PCA analysis on a big matrix using scikit

Tags: python, matrix, package, scikit-learn, pca

Hello I'm trying to use the scikit package for the first time (and python as well) and need some help.

Basically I have a huge 39x39 matrix and I need to do a Principle component analysis on them.

For context each row and column represents a country and the number inside represents a how much they gave to the country in the column, lets say UK, France and Sweden

0   1   1

8   0   1

8   1   0

The 0s indicate that a country couldn't vote for itself (eg UK gave UK 0 points) and 1 indicates they could vote for them but gave 0 points, and obviously 1-n is whatever point they gave to that country (France and Sweden both gave 7 points to the UK). I have the 1s and 0s because there are countries who voted but couldn't recieve points, they are at the end of the huge matrix.

I'm not sure if the format is even correct to do it, just looking for any guidance on how to go about this. Eventually I want to end up something looking similar to :

I think I've installed the package correctly and tested using the iris sample codes http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/datasets/plot_iris_dataset.html

file = open('rawresults2014eurovision.txt', 'rb')
table = [row.strip().split('\t') for row in file]

X = table

print(X)

I'm using Spyder to code it all I have so far is loading the data using this code

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Can you tell us the specific problem you have having with scikit-learn, and maybe edit your post to include the code you have so far?

Comment: I was referring to this problem specifically. What have you tried so far to do PCA?

Comment: I'm just not sure if I am even loading the data properly. Like I said I'm a complete novice to python and the scikit-learn package so looking for resources on how to go about actually compressing my matrix into a graph

Comment: Just FYI 39x39 is tiny for doing PCA.